# How to use count for object of class "Character"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame where in one column named "City" there are more than 50 different cities and if I plot a bar graph using city then it gets very difficult to read the plot.

Is there any way to first use `count()` to count the number of cities and then select top 15 cities based on how many time they appear in the data and after that using `ggplot()` plot a bar graph.

Comment: Can you provide the example data and show your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>%
   group_by(City) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   slice_max(n = 15, n) %>%
   left_join(df, by = 'City')
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep the rows for top 15 Cities you can do -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(City) %>%
  slice_max(n = 15, n) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'City') -> res

res
```

Or in base R -

```
res <- subset(df, City %in% tail(sort(table(City)), 15))
```